# Adding a custom datepicker to bokeh standard text input

Tags: python, input, bokeh

I'm trying to add a standard datepicker (like air datepicker) to a standard bokeh text input.

I added the JS references and I'm linking a class in the text input field like:

```
event = TextInput(title=u"Event Date", value=' ', css_classes=['datepicker-here'])
```

In theory, that should work, yet, it is not...
I also tried with other standard datepicker, to no success.

**Here is another case: flatpicker.**
A simple datepicker which works perfectly with this setup:

Create a simple text input:

event = TextInput(title=u"event", css_classes=['flatpkr'])

and put the required js code in the template.

flatpicker examples here (how it should work):

```js
$("input[type='text']").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "F, d Y H:i"
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/themes/dark.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Please select Date Time">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
</body>
```

If this is set in a plain webpage, everything is working properly. In Bokeh it does not, although I set exactly the same code in the template

```
{% extends base %}

{% block postamble %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
    {{ super() }}
    <!-- JS Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Flatpicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        flatpickr("input[type='text']", {
            "minDate": new Date().fp_incr(1)
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you able to share more of your code, as a minimal working example, so that it can be run in its entirety and inspected for the problem? Bokeh's built-in widgets always have lots of Bokeh-specific styles applied, so I am not sure I would expect this to work, but it's not really possible to say more without actual code.

Comment: just updated my post with the full example :) thanks for taking the time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra information confirms what I thought you intended, but is not actually enough to run and investigate. That said, contrary to your supposition *"In theory, that should work"*, I would actually never expect this to work. And the reason is that declaring a Bokeh `TextInput` does mean "just dump a bare `<input>` in the DOM". Rather, there is an entire JS implementation and CSS that Bokeh provides to support *its* version of a text input widget. In general, I have zero confidence that it would ever "just work" to have two different JS libraries fighting to control the same DOM element in their own separate ways.

If you want to do this sort of thing (i.e. integrate outside widgets seamlessly with Bokeh), it's possible, but the usual mechanism is by [Extending Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html). In particular see the example [Adding a Custom Widget](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/widget.html#userguide-extensions-examples-widget). A custom extension will have a Python object that represents it and that is automatically synchronized the same as any other Bokeh object.

Another (simpler) possibility: You could put HTML (including your plain `<input>`) in a Bokeh `Div`. Bokeh won't try to style or control any DOM elements added inside a `Div`. That might reasonably be expected to work (though I have not tried). A widget added this way will not have a Python counterpart that it is automatically synced with, but its not clear what your actual requirements are, so that might be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the div case, how can I get the data back from the div (a date will be entered, provided that works!). Also, Bokeh has its own datepicker. Can it be localized (spanish or else?)

Comment: It really depends, there's various possibilities. A plain JS callback on the widget could update a Bokeh CDS or other object. It's usually a bit tedious to trawl through `Bokeh.index` to find the necessary object, but it is done. Or the widget could  make an AJAX call that somehow informs the app session. It really very much depends. AFAIK the current datepicker cannot be localized. This is an area where the project team simply 100% needs more expertise and person-power to be able to do more. There is no quick fix for that. With no  budget to speak of, volunteers show up when they show up.

Comment: I'd be curious to investigate why (just to know), if you can post a complete MRE somewhere. Of course since you are using a template already, perhaps you can just put the `<input>` directly in the template? Might be reasonable, depending on your layout needs.